# CSS: Hover effect over image with width: auto

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a caption appear whenever I hover on the image. I want the height of the image to be set to 200px, but the width to be auto. How can I make the span with the caption also correspond to the image width? Thanks!

HTML:

```html
  <div class="projects">
   <a name="folder"></a>
   <h1 class="heading">Projects</h1>
    <p class="classProjectsInfo">Recent class projects</p>
    <div class="classProjects">
     <ul class="img-list">
      <li>
       <img src="checkers_cover.JPG">
       <span class="description2"><span>Checkers61B</span></span>
      </li>

      <li>
       <img src="cover_ngram.JPG">
       <span class="description2"><span>NGramMap</span></span>
      </li>

      <li>
       <img src="gitlet_cover.JPG">
       <span class="description2"><span>Gitlet</span></span>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.classProjects {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}



.classProjects li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 position: relative;
 height: 250px;
 width: auto;
}


.classProjects img {
 height: 250px;
 width: auto;
}



ul.img-list {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.img-list li {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 250px;
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
}

span.description2 {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: table;
   height: 250px;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: auto;
}

span.description2 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


span.description2 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
 
ul.img-list li:hover span.description2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be css only?

Comment: No I'm open to any suggestion :)

Comment: Never mind I've solved my problem. I just added another div around img and span, and set the div width as auto and the description width as 100%.

Comment: Haha, nice easy fix!

Comment: @clue11 you should answer our own question and accept your answer.